# Java 8 Type Annotations

Tags: java, types, annotations, java-8

This might be a standard Java 8 text book question, but I have been struggling to get an answer.

I declare a variable in an anonymous class

```
C c1 = new C () {
    @Anno1(sequence=1) @Anno2 StringVariable s = new @Anno3 StringVariable ("b");
}
```

I have an annotation Processor that needs to detect if the variable annotated with `@Anno2` is also annotated with `@Anno3` and do something special with the returned value (in my case, call an additional method on the assigned StringVariable).

I am however, unable to detect the presence of @Anno3. How do I get it?

My annotations are:
Anno1, Anno2, Anno3 all have similar definitions

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = {ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface Anno3 {}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Documented
public @interface Anno1 {
     int sequence();
}
```

and Anno2 is

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Documented
public @interface Anno2 {}
```

Comment: Can you specify the definition of anno2 and anno3? The relevent part of the processor could be usefull too

Comment: Show definitions for your custom annotations.